# How to show custom events to a Kronolith calendar

Tags: calendar, horde

I want to show events from an external source in the [Kronolith](http://www.horde.org/kronolith/) calendar views. I don't want to do this by exporting the events to iCal and then showing them as an external calendar. The events are grouped in multiple calendars, the user should be able to disable/enable these calendars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by implementing the `listTimeObjects` and `listTimeObjectCategories` API calls. [Nag](http://www.horde.org/nag/) (task list) and [Whups](http://www.horde.org/whups/) (ticket tracking) do it this way. If you are using the Git version, you can use [TimeObjects](http://theupstairsroom.com/93), which wraps everything up in a nice class.

Kronolith calls these functions in `initialize()` (when filling `$all_external_calendars`) and `listEvents()`. It searches all APIs for this function, so you can register it with your own prefix.

*timeObject* is a generic name for "things that can be shown on a calendar", like events, task due dates, ... A *timeObjectCategory* is a group of *timeObjects*, which can be enabled or disabled in a group by the user. (In the default layout: using the panel in the upper-right corner of the calendar view, "Calendars".)

Your implementation for `listTimeObjectCategories` should return an array, with a category id as the key, and the user-visible name as the value. The category id's are also shown at the bottom of the calendar, and the user can define colors for them.

`listTimeObjects` is called with the currently selected categories (an array of id's), and a start and end date. These dates might already be `Horde_Date` objects (to be sure, convert them again: `$start = new Horde_Date($start)`).

You should return an array of *timeObjects* that belong to these categories and fall in the specified time range. The keys are event id's, the values are arrays with values for the following keys:

- `id`
- `title`
- `description`
- `start` (`Horde_Date` or timestamp)
- `end` (`Horde_Date` or timestamp)
- `category` (Category id)
- `params`

If you register the `show` API call, this will be used for creating the link to the *timeObject* detail.